# Python ValueError and IndexError

Tags: python

I have been given a project to work on for school where I am to determine the number of elementary steps in two separate lists of cities.

When I try to run the project in order to answer this problem, I get two separate errors depending on which list I am trying to run.

Here is the code below

```
"""
This program sorts the words " London " , " Canterbury " , " York " and " Leicester "
by their length (in ascending order) and prints the result out.
"""

# First , we define our input as an array of strings
cities = ["London", "Canterbury", "York", "Leicester"]

# You can  also  try it with a very  long  list. Uncomment  this  line to do so.
#cities = ['Lancaster', 'Sunderland', 'Wolverhampton', 'Nottingham', 'Oxford', 'Plymouth', 'Salisbury', 'Salford', 'Wakefield', 'Lichfield', 'Wells', 'Preston', 'Brighton  and  Hove', 'St  Albans', 'Kingston  upon  Hull', 'Chichester', 'Durham', 'Liverpool', 'Bath', 'Bradford', 'Cambridge', 'Ely', 'York', 'Exeter', 'Birmingham', 'Carlisle', 'Portsmouth', 'Chester', 'Ripon', 'Coventry', 'Gloucester', 'Sheffield', 'Winchester', 'Lincoln', 'Canterbury', 'Westminster', 'Newcastle  upon  Tyne', 'Peterborough', 'Worcester', 'Leeds', 'Norwich', 'Stoke -on-Trent', 'Southampton', 'Bristol', 'Derby', 'Truro', 'Manchester', 'Hereford', 'City of  London', 'Leicester']

# Initialize our result , which will be empty for now
result = []

# Initialize our loop variables
i = 0
j = 0
number_of_cities = len(cities)
# len () of a list gives you the number of elements in it
# len () of a string will give you the length of it

n = number_of_cities
number_of_steps = 0

# Sort using selection sort
for i in range(0, number_of_cities):
    minimum_length = len(cities[0])
    minimum_element = cities[0]

    for j in range(0, n):
        if (len(cities[j]) < minimum_length):
            minimum_length = len(cities[j])
            minimum_element = cities[j]
            number_of_steps = number_of_steps + 1

        # At the end of the second loop , we will have the shorter element in minimum_element
        # We just need to add it to our results and remove it from our working list

        result.append(minimum_element)
        cities.remove(minimum_element)
        n = n - 1

print("")
print("The ordered list is:")
print(str(result))
print("The list had " + str(number_of_cities) + " cities and I ordered it in " + str(number_of_steps) + " steps .")
```

When I try to run the program with list `cities = ["London", "Canterbury", "York", "Leicester"]` I get the following error:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

When I try to run the program with list `cities = ['Lancaster', 'Sunderland', 'Wolverhampton', 'Nottingham', 'Oxford', 'Plymouth', 'Salisbury', 'Salford', 'Wakefield', 'Lichfield', 'Wells', 'Preston', 'Brighton  and  Hove', 'St  Albans', 'Kingston  upon  Hull', 'Chichester', 'Durham', 'Liverpool', 'Bath', 'Bradford', 'Cambridge', 'Ely', 'York', 'Exeter', 'Birmingham', 'Carlisle', 'Portsmouth', 'Chester', 'Ripon', 'Coventry', 'Gloucester', 'Sheffield', 'Winchester', 'Lincoln', 'Canterbury', 'Westminster', 'Newcastle  upon  Tyne', 'Peterborough', 'Worcester', 'Leeds', 'Norwich', 'Stoke -on-Trent', 'Southampton', 'Bristol', 'Derby', 'Truro', 'Manchester', 'Hereford', 'City of  London', 'Leicester']` I receive the following error `cities.remove(minimum_element) ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Any advice on how to fix this issue? I'm unsure if I can change the code much because this is what we have been given to work on. It's the holidays and all my lecturers are out of office so I'm unable to get any help. Thanks

Comment: John, instead of putting the whole long list of cities in the question (which everyone can already see in the code) you should instead put the full error messages, not just the final line.

Comment: Agree w/ what Pavel just said but would also like to add that some simple step through debugging will go a long way here.  To (hopefully) get you started on the right path, your first error is happening because you're indexing into the list using indices but you're removing elements from the list as you go, changing which indices you're allowed to read from (the error clearly says `list index out of range`).  Similarly your second error is clear that you're trying to remove an element from a list when that element is not present in that list.  Would recommend stepping through your code

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the state of the for cycle from the inside, but this doesn't work as you think it should. In particular, this line *does not* change the range of your iteration:

```
n = n - 1
```

For example:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l = len(s)

for i in range(l):
    print('Current value of l:', l)
    print('Current value of i:', i)
    print('Current list element:', s[i])
    l -= 1
    print('New value of l:', l)
    print('\n')
```

And the output:

```
Current value of l: 4
Current value of i: 0
Current list element: a
New value of l: 3


Current value of l: 3
Current value of i: 1
Current list element: b
New value of l: 2


Current value of l: 2
Current value of i: 2
Current list element: c
New value of l: 1


Current value of l: 1
Current value of i: 3
Current list element: d
New value of l: 0
```

You can see that we are reducing `l` by 1 in every iteration, but this doesn't stop `i` from going all the way to the original length of the list. In fact, this `l` that we are changing inside the cycle is a different `l` from what we used to start the cycle. Therefore, when you are removing elements from the list here:

```
result.append(minimum_element)
```

...you expect the iteration on the next cycle to be limited to the new value of `n` but in reality it will iterate until it reaches the *original* `n-1`. And since you have already removed items, you get an index error.

You might want to take a look at `while` loop instead and iterate until the original list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, let me explain, why there is no `result` variable.**

Selection sorting as any type of sorting algorythms is intented to modify initial array, not to create another. Since that I have not stored the result in a separate variable, I've sorted initial array and printed it.

```py
"""
This program sorts the words " London " , " Canterbury " , " York " and " Leicester "
by their length (in ascending order) and prints the result out.
"""

# First , we define our input as an array of strings
cities = ['Lancaster', 'Sunderland', 'Wolverhampton', 'Nottingham', 'Oxford', 'Plymouth', 'Salisbury', 'Salford', 'Wakefield', 'Lichfield', 'Wells', 'Preston', 'Brighton  and  Hove', 'St  Albans', 'Kingston  upon  Hull', 'Chichester', 'Durham', 'Liverpool', 'Bath', 'Bradford', 'Cambridge', 'Ely', 'York', 'Exeter', 'Birmingham', 'Carlisle', 'Portsmouth', 'Chester', 'Ripon', 'Coventry', 'Gloucester', 'Sheffield', 'Winchester', 'Lincoln', 'Canterbury', 'Westminster', 'Newcastle  upon  Tyne', 'Peterborough', 'Worcester', 'Leeds', 'Norwich', 'Stoke -on-Trent', 'Southampton', 'Bristol', 'Derby', 'Truro', 'Manchester', 'Hereford', 'City of  London', 'Leicester']

number_of_cities = len(cities)
# len () of a list gives you the number of elements in it
# len () of a string will give you the length of it

n = number_of_cities
number_of_steps = 0

# Sort using selection sort
for i in range(n - 1):
    smallest = i
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        if len(cities[j]) < len(cities[smallest]):
            smallest = j
    cities[i], cities[smallest] = cities[smallest], cities[i]
    number_of_steps += 1

print("The ordered list is:")
print(cities)
print("The list had " + str(number_of_cities) + " cities and I ordered it in " + str(number_of_steps) + " steps .")
```

Comment: Fedor, I believe John wants to manually implement selection sort algorithm. There's no use applying `sorted` here.

Comment: @pavel, thanks for reply, i've uptated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `cities.remove(minimum_element)`.

Example1

```
cities = ["London", "Canterbury", "York", "Leicester"]


for 0 
      if len(cities[0]) < minimum_length: 
           ...
cities = ['Canterbury', 'York', 'Leicester']

for 1 
      if len(cities[1]) < minimum_length:
           ...
cities = ['Canterbury', 'Leicester']

for 2 
      if len(cities[2]) < minimum_length:
           ...
cities[2] = Has been removed.
```

`if len(cities[j]) < minimum_length:` `IndexError: list index out of range`

Example2

```
cities = ['Lancaster', 'Sunderland', 'Wolverhampton', 'Nottingham', 'Oxford', 'Plymouth', 'Salisbury', 'Salford', 'Wakefield', 'Lichfield', 'Wells', 'Preston', 'Brighton  and  Hove', 'St  Albans', 'Kingston  upon  Hull', 'Chichester', 'Durham', 'Liverpool', 'Bath', 'Bradford', 'Cambridge', 'Ely', 'York', 'Exeter', 'Birmingham', 'Carlisle', 'Portsmouth', 'Chester', 'Ripon', 'Coventry', 'Gloucester', 'Sheffield', 'Winchester', 'Lincoln', 'Canterbury', 'Westminster', 'Newcastle  upon  Tyne', 'Peterborough', 'Worcester', 'Leeds', 'Norwich', 'Stoke -on-Trent', 'Southampton', 'Bristol', 'Derby', 'Truro', 'Manchester', 'Hereford', 'City of  London', 'Leicester']


minimum_length = len(cities[0])  = 9
minimum_element = cities[0] = 'Lancaster'

for 0
     if len(cities[0]) < minimum_length:   <-- if len('Lancaster') < 9 ?  NO!
           ....
cities.remove(minimum_element)

for 1 
     cities[1] = 'Wolverhampton'
     if len(cities[1]) < minimum_length: <-- if len('Wolverhampton') < 9 ?  NO!
            ....

cities.remove(minimum_element)  <--- error
```

`cities.remove(minimum_element) ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

I have told you the reason for the error.

Then modify it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, you can try `whileloop` instead.

```py
cities = ["London", "Canterbury", "York", "Leicester"]
result = []
while len(cities) > 0:
    minlen = len(cities[0])
    min_element = cities[0]
    for i in range(1, len(cities)):
        if len(cities[i]) < minlen:
            minlen = len(cities[i])
            min_element=cities[i]
    result.append(min_element)
    cities.remove(min_element)
```